# Select AR placed objects with a dot in the middle of the screen in Unity

Tags: augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I have seen numerous AR application behaving like this: there is a dot in the middle of the screen and we can position that dot on some objects and some content is displayed (I attacked an image if i was not clear enough). My question is how is this kind of behaviour obtained in Unity, my guess is that from that point you cast a ray, but I don't think that AR placed objects, from an ADF for example, can be found with the hit from that ray. [The dot selecting objects placed on AR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cs9V.jpg)

Comment: To use a raycast in Unity, the object needs to have a collider. PS: this looks like Schneider app, isn't it?

Comment: Nah, it is Romain Gassion's app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it work, with the aid of the Google Tango's Area Learning demo scene. I've placed some objects in the area and I have started to send a Raycast from the middle of the camera with "ViewportPointToRay" method. When that Ray would collide with a GameObject you can implement whatever functionality you need.